# Contract deploying but not initializing state variables

Tags: contract-development, contract-debugging

I'm deploying via Remix and Metamask.

I have an intializer `function MyToken() { ... }` that initializes a few state variables, and calls `test(); test();` at the end.

The contract deploys, but none of the state variables get initialized. When I remove `test(); test();`, it works.

Why could this be? If those two calls to `test()` produced an error, then wouldn't the contract simply not deploy?

## edit

When I deploy to "Javascript VM" rather than "Injected Web3", it works fine.

Just putting one call to `test();` works fine; so is it a gas problem? Why is the contract still deploying then?

Also, calling `test(); test();` manually (when it is not included in the intializer) works.

Comment: Can you post the contract?

Comment: Turns out it was a gas problem and the contract probably wasn't even deploying. Why Remix made it look like it deployed, I don't know.

Comment: You can post your own answer, and if you can edit your question and answer, it would probably be more helpful to readers since it's currently unclear :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the second call to `test()` was pushing the transaction above the gas limit. I guess the compiler couldn't compute that function's cost beforehand, so it let me deploy it. However, the result it presented me had every value zeroed out, so I don't think it was successfully deployed.